# The equation will not solve in swift cause of this error

Tags: ios, swift, math

```
let a: Double  = 9.1
let b: Double  = -1.1
let c: Double  = 1.3
root1: Double = (b + sqrt((b * b) - 4 * a * c)/(2 * a)
root2: Double = (b + sqrt((b * b) - 4 * a * c)/(2 * a)
print(root1)
print(root2)
```

Error is:

```
/tmp/560B3FBA-E1E9-48E8-B069-8958D75A2043.L2LFYF/main.swift:16:6: error: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
root1: Double = (b + sqrt((b * b) - 4 * a * c)/(2 * a)
     ^
     ;
/tmp/560B3FBA-E1E9-48E8-B069-8958D75A2043.L2LFYF/main.swift:16:6: error: expected expression
root1: Double = (b + sqrt((b * b) - 4 * a * c)/(2 * a)
     ^
/tmp/560B3FBA-E1E9-48E8-B069-8958D75A2043.L2LFYF/main.swift:16:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'root1'
root1: Double = (b + sqrt((b * b) - 4 * a * c)/(2 * a)
^~~~~
```

Comment: ios/swift is not i really like it :))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot "let" before `root1` and `root2`:

```swift
let a: Double  = 9.1
let b: Double  = -1.1
let c: Double  = 1.3
let root1: Double = (b + sqrt((b * b) - 4 * a * c)/(2 * a)
let root2: Double = (b + sqrt((b * b) - 4 * a * c)/(2 * a)
print(root1)
print(root2)
```

There are further issues that I didn't notice, as Duncan pointed out.

You can find out if a quadratic function has zero, one or two distinct real roots by looking at the sign of the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant). Since we'll be calculating multiple values (the discriminant, and up to two roots) from a set of related values, that's a perfect chance to use a `struct`.

Here I model the three Doubles that represent the quadratic function using a struct called... `QuadraticFunction`. You can then ask that function for the value of its discriminant, and for a solution. I also made a helper function which builds a nice English description of the solution.

```swift
import Foundation

struct QuadraticFunction {
    let a, b, c: Double
    
    var discriminant: Double { b*b - 4*a*c }
    
    enum Roots {
        case two(Double, Double)
        case one(Double)
        case none
    }
    
    func solve() -> Roots {
        switch self.discriminant {
            case let d where d < 0: return Roots.none // No real roots
            
            case let d where d == 0: return .one((b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a))
            
            case let d where d > 0: return .two(
                    (b - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a),
                    (b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
                )
                
            default: fatalError("Unreachable")
        }
    }
}

extension QuadraticFunction: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        "\(a)x² + \(b)x + \(c)"
    }
}

func prettyPrintSolution(of function: QuadraticFunction) {
    let solution = function.solve()
    
    switch solution {
        case .none: print("The equation \(function) has no real roots.")
        case .one(let r): print("The equation \(function) has one distinct root \(r).")
        case .two(let r1, let r2): print("The equation \(function) has two distinct roots \(r1) and \(r2).")
    }
}

let function1 = QuadraticFunction(a: 9.1, b: -1.1, c: 1.3)
prettyPrintSolution(of: function1)

let function2 = QuadraticFunction(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0)
prettyPrintSolution(of: function2)

let function3 = QuadraticFunction(a: 1, b: 0, c: -1)
prettyPrintSolution(of: function3)
```

Result:

```
The equation 9.1x² + -1.1x + 1.3 has no real roots.
The equation 1.0x² + 0.0x + 0.0 has one distinct root 0.0.
The equation 1.0x² + 0.0x + -1.0 has two distinct roots -1.0 and 1.0.
```

Comment: D*mn, dude! That's quite an answer! Well done, sir. (Voted.)

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems with your code:

1. You are missing lets on the root1 and root2, as Alexander said:
2. You have unbalanced parentheses in those lines
3. The expressions you are passing to `sqrt()` evaluate to negative numbers, so you are getting NAN (not a number) results. (The square root of a negative number is an imaginary number.)

```
let root1: Double = b + sqrt((b * b) - 4 * a * c)/(2 * a)
let root2: Double = b + sqrt((b * b) - 4 * a * c)/(2 * a)
```

Comment: "sqrt() evaluate to negative numbers" ok, that's an impressive catch.

Comment: The actual question is this :                                                                                               a⋅x² + b⋅x + c = 0 b                                                                                                           x = (-b + sqrt(b² - 4 * a * c)/(2 * a)                                                                    
so i found the solution that I made a negative number of b, I totally  understood your's answer.. Alexander's solution is complex for me but it is working!

Comment: Oh wow. He went all out with a solution. By all means, accept his. It is a complete solution to the problem you were trying to solve.

Comment: Hey Duncan thank you for your comments I am really appreciated but I put the "let" but it did not work man :/